# Name of place where there are many buildings?

Tags: single-word-requests

In some countries, in a closed area, more than one building (mostly apartment buildings) is constructed, and the place is given a name. Then buildings are named A, B, C etc.

What is such an area called? I would say "building area", though am not sure about that.

Comment: It's a built-up area.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If the apartments are dwellings, I would call the whole area "a condo"  or "condominium" (some definitions include [non-residential use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condominium#United_States), though.)

> - condo - "short for condominium"
> - condominium - "a building or complex of buildings containing a number of individually owned apartments or houses." [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=dwelling+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=SPv_VeTsJseB8Qfng5WgDw&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=define+condominium)
>
>   "a building or complex in which units of property, such as apartments, are owned by individuals and common parts of the property, such as the grounds and building structure, are owned jointly by the unit owners." [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/condominium)

For a complete review on the subject see: [Condominium - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condominium)

[image]

The Cosmopolitan, a condominium in Singapore

Comment: In the U.S. (excepting New York City), *apartments* and *condominiums* are distinguished by their ownership structure. Unless the apartments are individually owned, the right words are *"an apartment building"* or *"an apartment complex"*. And I've never heard a condominium complex called a *condominium* (although this concept comes up so rarely in my conversations that people might use this without my hearing it).

Comment: @PeterShor In Massachusetts I've heard people call this form of housing tenure a "condo" ("I live in a condo") or, more rarely, "a condominium".  I once lived in a condo in Central Massachusetts and it was just like the definitions I've found (apartment buildings, gym room, swimming pool, etc, in a restricted area)

Comment: Note that "complex" in your quote actually answers the question.

Comment: Condominium is a form of ownership, where each unit may have a different owner. You wouldn't call it a condominium if there's a single owner of the building and he rents the apartments.

Comment: Updated the question. I would say multiple apartment buildings instead of multiple apartments. So, there is a place, and in there, there are 3 separate apartment buildings. Then let's say, all these buildings are called as "The beautiful people". First apartment building is called A, second one as B, third one as C.

Comment: @tcak It'd still be called an apartment __complex__. For example, I live in Building 11 of my apartment complex (I really do by the way).

Comment: condos can be made up of more than one building. But, in urban planning parlance, the term is a complex [meaning: more than one building. residential or not]. condo is really a term that describes ownership. condo versus a coop (NYC: cooperative apartment building) or rental apartments.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: as others have pointed out, *condominium* refers to an ownership arrangement, and has nothing to do with what sort building or buildings are involved. It is perfectly possible, common even, for a condominium to be a single structure, i.e. nothing at all like what the question is asking for.

Comment: @Marthaª No answer will be considered current usage or correct in every corner of the US.  Never mind in other English speaking countries.  Anyway, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: ps.  I can't delete an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that most of the space in the buildings is occupied by private residences, the most general term for what the question is about, which is likely to be readily understood throughout the English-speaking world, is ***housing complex***.

In British English, the term ***housing estate*** is often used.

An alternative term is ***housing development***. As that term focuses on the process by which the complex came into being, it is particularly likely to be used while it is being built, and when it is relatively new.

If the residences in the complex are intended to be offered at low rents, subsidised by the government, the complex may be referred to, in American English, as a ***housing project***. (In American English, the phrase is used only in this, very specific, sense, notwithstanding the fact that the meanings of the words that constitute it might lead one to expect it to have a wider meaning.)

If the ownership of the residences in the complex takes the legal form of a condominium, the complex may be referred to as a ***condominium complex***.

If the complex is fenced off from the surrounding area, and entry into it is restricted to the residents, their guests, and those who have specific business in it, the complex may be called a ***gated community***. That term is essentially synonymous with ***compound***, but people in the real-estate business would never use the latter term, because some associations carried by it can make the place look unappealing.

Of course, if the complex has some specific further purpose, it will be referred to by that purpose, as, say, a university campus, retirement community, etc.

Comment: housing complex in American English is usually made up of houses, not apartments and in the UK, affordable housing is called a housing estate. In the US, housing project, yes.

Comment: @Lambie — A UK housing estate does not equate to US “affordable housing” although it will include some of that type — council houses  on. council house estate — if any such remain. A housing estate can be in housing development undertaken generally by a single building company, but does imply individual or semi-detached houses, as you say. Groups of public high-rise flats (US apartments) do not have a consistent name to my knowledge. In Glasgow they might be referred to as a “scheme”, but not, I think, elsewhere.

Comment: @David I guess I was thinking of a council estate and council flat. Mea culpa. :)